# How can I get past this "'django_content_type' does not exist" error when deploying with Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, wagtail

I'm trying to deploy my first real website with Heroku. I successfully deployed once in the past with a super simple website, but I seem to be stuck this time. I'm able to run the site locally fine.

When I click Deploy for Free on Heroku, it successfully Creates app, Configures environment, and Builds app. The error comes from the Run scripts & scale dynos part saying 'postdeploy exit code was not 0'

I'm using Django 1.9.4 with [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) to start my project. I also added [wagtail](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail) to my project and made some fairly simple pages with it. If you need to see any of my other files please let me know. I'm at a loss with this one.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...

                                                             ^



The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 67, in get_for_model
    ct = self.get(app_label=opts.app_label, model=opts.model_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 381, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 240, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...

                                                             ^



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py", line 572, in check
    if not issubclass(edit_handler.get_form_class(cls), WagtailAdminPageForm):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 294, in get_form_class
    formsets=cls.required_formsets(),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 240, in required_formsets
    formsets.update(handler_class.required_formsets())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 240, in required_formsets
    formsets.update(handler_class.required_formsets())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 603, in required_formsets
    'widgets': child_edit_handler_class.widget_overrides(),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 216, in widget_overrides
    widgets.update(handler_class.widget_overrides())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 216, in widget_overrides
    widgets.update(handler_class.widget_overrides())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 516, in widget_overrides
    content_type=cls.target_content_type(), can_choose_root=cls.can_choose_root)}
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 543, in target_content_type
    cls._target_content_type = [ContentType.objects.get_for_model(target_model)]
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 80, in get_for_model
    "Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes "
RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.
```

Comment: Try upgrading to Wagtail 1.4.3 if you're not on it already - the latest release fixes a couple of issues related to bringing up a project database from scratch.

Comment: @gasman That did it. I was using 1.4.2 all this time. Funny story, about 5 minutes before your post I ended up dropping my database and creating it again because I was desperate. But I don't even care I'm so happy! Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to Wagtail 1.4.3 if you're not on it already - the latest release fixes a couple of issues related to bringing up a project database from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to run the migration command using:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I added my app.json file for using the deploy button with Heroku. I believe it's using the `"scripts": {"postdeploy": "python manage.py migrate"}` command to do this automatically? I'll try it on the command line though.

Comment: Update - I tried deploying from the command line instead of with the deploy heroku button. I get the same error. I push everything to heroku fine, but when running `heroku run python manage.py migrate` I get the same error as I posted above. This is so frustrating, I feel like I'm so close to finally having a project live.

Comment: can you share your `settings.py` file

Comment: Yes. I've added my common.py, local.py, and production.py files. I haven't changed much from the defaults that were set up by [django-cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django). I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Also I don't know if this matters, but I just realized my copy/paste of the error was slightly off. I corrected the position of the ^ character pointing at: LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...

Comment: Make sure that you have Postgres Database addon linked to your in Heroku Dashboard